# Product of roots of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

I am confused as to why the product of the roots of $$az^n + z + 1$$ is $$\frac{(-1)^n}{a}$$

Can We generalize to other polynomials? Thank you!

This is in the solution of an exercise that uses Rouché's theorem in complex analysis.

Comment: Yes, this is implied by the Vieta's formulas.

Comment: Take a look at [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), (not to be mistaken for [Viète's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the roots of a monic polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ be $\alpha_i, i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Then we have

$$p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i)$$

and the constant term is $p(0)=\prod_{i=1}^n(-\alpha_i)=(-1)^n\prod_{i=1}^n\alpha_i $

Try to make your polynomial monic and see the result.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial factors as

$$a(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots(z-z_n)$$ and the independent term is given by

$$P(0)=a(-z_1)(-z_2)\cdots(-z_n)$$

which is know to be $1$.